# XCode 4.3.2 Application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have installed XCode 4.3.2 on Lion 10.7.3
I try to distribute my application in AppStore, but when I do validate, I get error message:
"iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7", but i have this architecture in target settings.

I added "armv6" to Architectures in Build Settings (as recommended by many people), but it's didn't work for me.
Here are Build settings of my project:

---Architetures---

Architetures                   - Standard (armv7)

Release                      - Standard (armv7)

Base SDK                       - Latest iOS (iOS 5.1.)

Build Active Architecture Only - No

Supported Platforms            - iphonesimulator iphoneos

Valid architectures            - armv7

---Build Options---

Build variants - normal

Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C - Default compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 3.1)

Comment: Are you trying to submit the x86 Simulator build instead of the iOS device build?

Comment: Building for iOS 5.1 Simulator is success. After all i installed Mac OS X 10.7.4 for installing  XCode 4.5.1. Building for iOS 6.0 Simulator is success, but when i try build for iOS device, i get error: "ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o for architecture armv6". By the way i don't need to build for armv6(!). How i can drop armv6 support from my project?

Comment: @hotpaw2 Just FYI: there's no way you can submit a simulator build. It won't let you archive unless you select to build for an iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to the updated question in your comment:

To drop armv6 support under Xcode 4.5.x, raise the iOS Deployment Target to 4.3 or higher, and remove armv6 from the build architectures and active architectures for your Target.

Added: You can't do this if you included any 3rd party libraries that are armv6-only, until you get newer updated libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Deployment target of my project is 6.0. I didn't added armv6 to build architectures in XCode 4.5.1. Why i get this error about armv6?

Comment: Is this a project created before XCode 4.5.x?  If so, that's were all previous architectures came from.  Just find and remove all armv6 mentions from all multiple projects and target settings.

Comment: Thanks. This project created with Delphi XE2 and ported to XCode with FreePascal 2.6.0 and Firemonkey. How I can remove all armv6 mentions?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated Firemonkey by Update 4 Hotfix 1 and it's all compiled.
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2012/04/12/39245

Thanks to all!